# how to check whether it contains some string from the inclusive list but not from the exclusive list in C#

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

> How to check whether the string is present in the urgent list. if an
> urgent word contains in the non-urgent list it should be false

if the urgent word is present in the urgent list and the non-urgent list also m then it's giving false which is an unexpected result.
c#

````
    var mydata =
    "one two URGENT three four
    if you are not the intended recipient, immediately send it back" // exp op - Yes
    ```
    var mydata =
    "one two three four
    if you are not the intended recipient, immediately send it back" //exp op - NO

Desired OUTPUT - Yes. but coming as No
Conditions - urgent word contains in the urgent list but not in the nonurgent list then only it should give as true/Yes.

``` c#
var urgentList= new List<string>()
                    {
                        "Urgent",
                        "Immediate",
                         immediately 

                    };
var nonUrgentList= new List<string>()
                    {
                        "Important information: urgent send",
                        "notice immediately",
                        "Important notice: urgent ",
                         "immediately send it back"
                    };

string [] wordDelimiters = {""}
var indicator = mydata
    .split(wordDelimiter,StringSlitOptions.None)
    .Any(word=>urgentList.contains(word,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnorCase)) &&
    nonUrgentList.All(x=>!mydata.Contains(x.StringComparision.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        ? "Yes"
        :"No";
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Given

- `List<string> data` - list to check
- `List<string> include` - list of strings that data must contain at least one of
- `List<string> exclude` - list of strings that data must not contain

then

```cs
var indicator = data.Where(str => include.Contains(str) && !exclude.Contains(str)).Any() ? "Yes" : "No";
```

(This addresses the question expressed in the original title but the details seem to be changing.)

Comment: my data is var . not the list. i cant use where clause with "mydata"

Comment: Your `mydata` is a `string`.  `mydata.split()` returns a collection, specifically a `string[]` array.